# Normalized VIKOR method multicriteria

Tags: multicriteria-decision-analysis

I would like some help with regards to understanding why the author of an article normalized differently just for the results of the `VIKOR` multicriteria method. I'll insert an image for you to read the excerpt that talks about it. It is a study that uses 5 multi-criteria methods. However, the way to normalize `VIKOR` he did `(max-x)/(max-min)` and not `(x-min)/(max-min)` like he did in the others. I read the whole article and he doesn't explain why.

The reason would be because of the final result obtained `VIKOR`, that is, index `Q`, where the smallest value is chosen as the best, so for this reason he changed the normalization approach? In others multicriteria methods he used, the highest value is the best.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You're absolutely correct.

Basically, whenever normalization is done in MCDM methods, the designer has to see whether the criteria is a benefit criteria (for which the higher the value, the better it is) or it is a cost criteria (for which the lower the value, the better it is). Seeing that, we normalize things.

For example:

Just have a look at the table 1 of this paper:
[Normalization Techniques for Multi-Criteria Decision Making: Analytical Hierarchy Process Case Study](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-31165-4_26)

[image: Max Min criteria]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand this criterion issue, but in the image, it says that the result of the VIKOR method will be normalized, that is, the Q index. This result is normalized differently from the results of the other methods. Why just the VIKOR method, you know? That's what I didn't quite understand.